# R group or aggregate

Tags: r, group-by, aggregate

I would like to do a group_by or aggregate. I have something like:

```
> head(affiliation_clean)
  Affiliation_ID                       Affiliation_Name          City       Country
1       000001   New Mexico State University Las Cruces    Las Cruces United States
2       000001   New Mexico State University Las Cruces    Las Cruces          <NA>
3       000001   New Mexico State University Las Cruces          <NA>          <NA>
4       000002   Palo Alto Research Center Incorporated     Palo Alto          <NA>
5       000002   Palo Alto Research Center Incorporated          <NA> United States
6       000002   Palo Alto Research Center Incorporated          <NA>          <NA>
```

Grouping by "Affiliation_ID" and taking the longest string of "Affiliation_Name", "City" and "Country", I would like to get:

```
> head(affiliation_clean)
  Affiliation_ID                       Affiliation_Name          City       Country
1       000001   New Mexico State University Las Cruces    Las Cruces United States
2       000002   Palo Alto Research Center Incorporated     Palo Alto United States
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `df1 %>% group_by_at(1:2) %>% summarise_all(funs(unique(.[!is.na(.)]))`

Comment: Do you just wan to get rid of your NA values so that the unique values in City and Country are paired with the Affiliation_ID and Affiliation_Name columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `dplyr` solution based on your description to select the longest string of each `Affiliation_ID` and column.

```
library(dplyr)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  group_by(Affiliation_ID) %>%
  summarise_all(funs(.[which.max(nchar(.))][1]))
dat2
# # A tibble: 2 x 4
#   Affiliation_ID Affiliation_Name                       City       Country      
#            <int> <chr>                                  <chr>      <chr>        
# 1              1 New Mexico State University Las Cruces Las Cruces United States
# 2              2 Palo Alto Research Center Incorporated Palo Alto  United States
```

**DATA**

```
dat <-read.table(text = "  Affiliation_ID                       Affiliation_Name          City       Country
1       '000001'   'New Mexico State University Las Cruces'    'Las Cruces' 'United States'
                 2       '000001'   'New Mexico State University Las Cruces'    'Las Cruces'          NA
                 3       '000001'   'New Mexico State University Las Cruces'          NA          NA
                 4       '000002'   'Palo Alto Research Center Incorporated'     'Palo Alto'          NA
                 5       '000002'   'Palo Alto Research Center Incorporated'          NA 'United States'
                 6       '000002'   'Palo Alto Research Center Incorporated'          NA          NA",
                 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that there is a single `unique` 'City/Country' for each 'Affiliation_ID', 'Affiliation_Name', after grouping at the first two columns, get the `unique` non-NA element of all other columns with `summarise_all`

```
library(dplyr)
affiliation_clean %>%
   group_by(Affiliation_ID, Affiliation_Name) %>%
   summarise_all(funs(unique(.[!is.na(.)])) )
# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups: Affiliation_ID [?]
#  Affiliation_ID Affiliation_Name                       City       Country      
#  <chr>          <chr>                                  <chr>      <chr>        
#1 000001         New Mexico State University Las Cruces Las Cruces United States
#2 000002         Palo Alto Research Center Incorporated Palo Alto  United States
```